# Matchwithlist in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

Over here i have an example of implementing matchwithlist in vb.net
how ever is there any other ways to do this.
In vb the code was simple `combo1.matchwithlist`
The got was taken from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266265/en-us

```
Private Sub Combo1_Change()

    Dim listcount As Integer
    Dim textlen As Integer
    Dim matchexists As Boolean

    textlen = Len(Combo1.Text)
    For listcount = 0 To Combo1.listcount - 1
        If UCase(Mid(Combo1.List(listcount), 1, textlen)) = UCase(Combo1.Text) Then
            matchexists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not matchexists Then
        MsgBox "Value not present in the list... Kindly enter a valid value.."
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Combo1.AddItem "Sam"
    Combo1.AddItem "Paul"
    Combo1.AddItem "Peter"
    Combo1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: In VB.NET you could use a LINQ expression to make the check a pretty much a one-liner

Comment: I suggest to to compare the strings with `str1.Equals(str2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` instead, and the use of `MessageBox.Show("")` instead of the deprecated `MsgBox`

Comment: And, by the way, since this code is not yours, maybe you could think on adding the **proper attribution** from MSDN: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266265/en-us

Comment: YuriyGalanter do you happen to have a sample code of doing that

Comment: I will edit that in my decsription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.TextChanged
    Dim Result As Boolean = False
    For Each itm As String In ComboBox1.Items
        If InStr(itm, ComboBox1.Text, CompareMethod.Text) <> 0 Then
            Result = True
        End If
    Next
    If Not Result Then
        MsgBox("No Match")
    End If
End Sub
```

This will compare the text entered after each character is typed, and display the messagebox if the text can't be found in any of the combobox items, ignoring case